# how to separate words in an input using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to separate words in an input using Javascript or Jquery lib ?
for example , someone has more than one interests and every time he separates between two interests using space or pressing enter a box Surrounds every single interests

or in other way , just like the tags here , every tags are separated by a box

Comment: it will be better to use an existing library for this like the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option here to look into is select2 http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/‎

Answer (score 0):

Detect the enter key in a keypress event and prevent default, then do your box wrapping.

Edit: a [A FIDDLE FOR YOU SIR](http://jsfiddle.net/seano666/2SDrP/2/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").on("keypress", function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
           e.preventDefault(); //take away carriage return if needed
            boxUp();
        }
    });
});
function boxUp(){
    val = $("#input").val();
    $("#result").append("<div>" + val + "</div>");
    v$("#input").val("");
}
```